# Interpret HTML tags in String

Tags: twig

I am using Twig template in my project and I have a WYSWYG editor to keep what the users want in the database...

Now in my template part I retrieve the content like this : `{{ datas.post.getContent()}}` and when I'm viewing my page the result is like this:

```
&lt;p&gt;Hello, &lt;em&gt;how are you doing&lt;/em&gt;?&lt;    /p&gt;&lt;p&gt;I admit &lt;strong&gt;I am not fine&lt;/strong&gt;, it&amp;#39;s not working...&lt;/p&gt;
```

So I tried the raw version or the striptag or the autoescape ...

```
{% autoescape %}
    {{ datas.post.getContent()}}
    // {{ datas.post.getContent()|raw}}
    // {{ datas.post.getContent()|striptags}}
{% endautoescape %}
```

but everything I try give me this result

`<p>Hello, <em>how are you doing</em>?</p><p>I admit <strong>I am not fine</strong>, it&#39;s not working...</p>`

I tryed putting the cache environnement to false... But nothing happen...
And I want this result :

> Hello, *how are you doing*? 
> I admit **I am not fine**, it's not
>   working...

What is the correct way?

Comment: Is your template included elsewhere?
The correct way is `{% autoescape %}{{ safe_value|raw }}{% endautoescape %}` but if you have only this in the autoescape then `autoescape` is not usefull

Comment: As @goto says, u need to use the `raw`-filter

Comment: As I said, if I made this with the autoescape I have something like this : `<p>Hello, <em>how are you doing</em>?</p><p>I admit <strong>I am not fine</strong>, <u>it&#39;s not working</u>...</p> ` so this is not my solution...

Comment: Is your code included somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Ok my bad...
I didn't see another developper made a htmlspecialchars function ...
So I first decoded it in my controller then rendered it with `{{ datas.post.getContent()|raw }}` (and I could remove the autoescaping...)

Sorry for disturbing...

Answer (score -1):

Probably you save converted data in database. Check format of saved html.
Or may be before pass data to view you have some kind of htmlspecialchars.

Comment: I made a var_dump just before rendering my Twig view in my controller and this is the data PHP give me from my database : `<p>Hello, <em>how are you doing</em>?</p><p>I admit <strong>I am not fine</strong>, <u>it&#39;s not working</u>...</p>`

Comment: My bad, you were right, I didn't see the htmlspecialchars function... sorry